# GridView is not being updated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to code a simple Boggle app. There's a "Shuffle Board" button which is supposed to shuffle all the cubes and show the new board.

The problem is: even though I update the `LetterAdapter` (inside `LetterAdapter#shuffle`, I call `notifyDataSetChanged`) AND use any combination of `refreshDrawableState()`, `invalidate()`, `invalidateViews()` inside `onClick` I can't get the view to being updated. The only working way I could find is to reassign the adapter to the `GridView`.

Why don't `refreshDrawableState()`, `invalidate()`, `invalidateViews()` or `notifyDataSetChanged` work? Why don't they have any effect visually?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final GridView letterGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.letter_grid);
        final LetterAdapter letterAdapter = new LetterAdapter(this);
        letterGrid.setAdapter(letterAdapter);

        Button shuffleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shuffle_button);
        shuffleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                letterAdapter.shuffle();
                // --------------- RELEVANT PART
                // letterGrid.refreshDrawableState();
                // letterGrid.invalidate();
                // letterGrid.invalidateViews();
                letterGrid.setAdapter(letterAdapter);
                // --------------- END
            }
        });
    }

    public class LetterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        private BoggleBoard mBoggleBoard;

        public LetterAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            mBoggleBoard = new BoggleBoard();
        }

        public void shuffle() {
            mBoggleBoard.shuffle();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return BoggleBoard.NUM_OF_CUBES;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mBoggleBoard.getLetter(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final Button letterButton;
            final String curLetter = mBoggleBoard.getLetter(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                letterButton = new Button(mContext);
                letterButton.setText(curLetter);
            } else {
                letterButton = (Button) convertView;
            }
            return letterButton;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I have read about a dozen relevant questions/answers but couldn't find any satisfying answer for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `getView` method. You should call `letterButton.setText(curLetter);` outside the condition.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Button letterButton;
    final String curLetter = mBoggleBoard.getLetter(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        letterButton = new Button(mContext);            
    } else {
        letterButton = (Button) convertView;            
    }

    letterButton.setText(curLetter);        
    return letterButton;
}
```

Comment: Ooops.. Shouldn't have missed this! Thanks!